# ThreeJS CSS3DRenderer Lights

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add some lights to the scene but because of browser restrictions I can use CSS3DRenderer only.

Can I use lights with this type of renderer?

I've been trying to add this code but it doesn't seem to work

```
var ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
scene.add(ambiLight);
var spotLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set(-20, 30, 40);
spotLight.intensity = 1.5;
scene.add(spotLight);
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW, which browsers are restricting you to CSS only?

Comment: Well, it's because I'm projecting some divs onto a sphere and it's easier using CSS3DRenderer (I think), also because WebGL is not fully supported on mobile devices

Comment: Why not use `CanvasRenderer` and `CSS3DRenderer` both?

Comment: Well I need to add hexagons to a sphere and to be honest I think is easier with divs rather than canvas and points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `CSS3DRenderer` does not support lights.

You can fake lighting, of course, by judicious choice of your div colors. (In other words, bake the lighting in.)

three.js r.65

Comment: Many Thanks. Any examples of how to do this?

Comment: No examples of that, sorry. It just means you can make divs that face the light lighter. If orientations are changing, however, then you have to do it on the fly.